# How to check values are inserted or not in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have values 3 seperated by comma like (AC,BC,MC).Some times the valuse will be AC only or AC,BC or AC,MC etc

I want to check it according to f_id from table like below

```html
id    f_id    value

1      1       AC

2      1       BC

3      1       MC

4      2       AC

5      3       MC
```

If any value is not in the table then I need insert it according to f_id

How to do  this?

Comment: i don't fully understand what you are trying to accomplish. you have an input with say `ac,bc`, both exist, so nothing should happen right? where does f_id come in to play?

Comment: f_id is the customer_id inserted with value like AC,BC.. on first submit.when same customer want add one more value like MC then above scenario comes @Alex

Comment: right, so f_id is submitted along with the values?

Comment: yes  f_id is submitted along with the values @Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically, you want to explode the user input string and get all the results for the current user and compare them. if a value exists in the db that exists in the user input then we don't do anything, if it doesn't then we perform an insert.

```
$input = 'AC,BC';
$f_id = 1;

$items = explode(',', $input);

$res = $this->db->get_where('yourtablename', array('f_id', $f_id))->result_array();

$values = array_column($res, 'value');

foreach ($items as $index => $value) {

   $value = trim($value); // remove whitespace; you might want to do more filtering/data manipulation than this

   if (!in_array($value, $values)) {
       $data = array('f_id' => $f_id, 'value' => $value);
       $this->db->insert('yourtablename', $data);
   }

}
```